# Apache Camel Mapstruct integration

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, mapstruct

In my Springboot Camel microservice I integrate camel mapstruct with this dependency:

```
<camel.version>3.20.1</camel.version>
<mapstruct.version>1.5.3.Final</mapstruct.version>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>${camel.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-mapstruct-starter</artifactId>
    <version>${camel.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
    <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
    <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
    <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
    <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I also have a mapper like this:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface CamelTestMapper {

    @BeanMapping(nullValueMappingStrategy = NullValueMappingStrategy.RETURN_DEFAULT)
    CamelTestDto mapCamelTestEntity(CamelTestEntity camelTestEntity);

}
```

and a route like this:

```
from("direct:get-by-id")
                .routeId("db-get-by-id-route")
                .transacted()
                .process(camelTestSampleDatabaseProcessor)
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Retrieved entity from db with name: ${body.name}")
                .to("mapstruct:org.example.model.dto.CamelTestDto")
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Mapped new Dto: ${body}");
```

I can't understand why in this way it works, and when I use

```
.convertBodyTo(CamelTestDto.class)
```

it throw this exception:

```
org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException: No body available of type: org.example.model.dto.CamelTestDto but has type: org.example.model.entity.CamelTestEntity on: Message[4939598FD4DFE7C-0000000000000103]. 
    Caused by: No type converter available to convert from type: org.example.model.entity.CamelTestEntity to the required type: org.example.model.dto.CamelTestDto. Exchange[4939598FD4DFE7C-0000000000000103]. 
    Caused by: [org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException - No type converter available to convert from type: org.example.model.entity.CamelTestEntity to the required type: org.example.model.dto.CamelTestDto]
```

Obviously I already set the application .yml in this way:

```
camel:
  component:
    mapstruct:
      mapper-package-name: org.example.mapper
```

Does anyone know how to solve it? Can you give to me some examples of how to use this integrations? Also with conversion with List please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a recent bug in camel-mapstruct-starter for SB that it did not auto-configure itself correctly, when you did not use mapstruct as a component in the routes.

This will be fixed in upcoming Camel releases:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-19181

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this, but I'm guessing Camel wants a bean annotated as a typeconverter to use for the .convertBodyTo directive.

Since the actual converter is a generated class I'm not sure how you would do that... maybe there's a way to define it in an XML file Camel reads.